# PHP embutido em HTML no Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, formatação, configuração

Bom dia:

Estou iniciando o uso do Eclipse Ide (Mars) porque ele já tem suporte ao PHP 7 enquanto que o NetBeans ainda não o tem.

Estou enfrentando um problema que é a não formatação (highlitgh syntaxe) de PHP quando embutido em código HTML.

No caso, tenho um arquivo index.php com código HTML e no BODY tem código PHP que o Eclipse não está formatando nem aplicando highlight syntaxe nele (apenas no código PHP).

Alguém sabe como corrigir isso, ois pesquisei no Google e nada encontrei sobre.

Comment: tem certeza que o código esta  formatado corretamente? fechou o <?php ?> ?

Comment: Poste o codigo ai.

Comment: Coloca um screenshot.

Comment: Talvez vc tem que instalar algum tema ou plugin de indentação e visualização do código, mas antes tente fazer isso manualmente: http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.php.help%2Fhtml%2Ftasks%2Fformatting_code.html
Use o comando `Ctrl + Shift + F`
http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.php.help%2Fhtml%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fcode_style_preferences%2Fformatter.html

Comment: Para ajustar a syntaxe:http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.php.help%2Fhtml%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Feditor%2Fsyntax_coloring.html&cp=61_4_3_5_5

Comment: Ctrl + Shif + F funcionou! Obrigado Ivan Ferrer

Comment: Você resolveu o problema?

Answer (score 1):

Não achei resposta para o problema do Eclipse mas achei a solução para o NetBeans: basta instalar a versão em desenvolvimento que já dá suporte ao PHP7.

Estava tentando usar o Eclipse porque o NetBeans não tinha o suporte. Com o suporte na versão em desenvolvimento do NB, deixei o eclipse de lado.